# Solving a complex equation including $\Im (z)$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Solve the following complex equation:
$$
e^{z+5} + e^{\overline z} + i\operatorname{Im}(z) 
= 6 + i\tfrac{π}{3} 
$$
I tried using the cartesian form of a complex number $z$ meaning $z=x+iy$ where $x$ and $y$ are the real and the imaginary part of $z$, respectfully.

Doing some basic calculations (algebra), I conclude that the following system of equations must be valid:
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
e^x \cos y &= \frac{6}{e^5+1} \\[2pt]
e^x \sin y &= \frac{\frac{π}{3}-y}{e^5-1}
\end{aligned} 
\right. 
$$

I do not know how to solve this system. I tried to divide the $2$ equations but then there is a tany to the LHS and a $y$ to the RHS. I also tried to write $i\operatorname{Im}z$ as $e^{\operatorname{Log}(\operatorname{Im}z)}$ where $\operatorname{Log}$ is the principal branch of complex logarithmic function.

Comment: Very mysteriously, I find graphically very many solutions which seem to have the same $x$ coordinate and are periodic in $y$. But that doesn’t make sense… but how can we expect to find the solutions to:  $$\tan(y)=\frac{\frac{\pi}{3}-y}{6}\cdot\frac{e^5+1}{e^5-1}$$Which is one of those impossible equations? Where did you get this problem? This seems achievable only numerically

Comment: @FShrike. Almost the same $x$ effectively. One more time for approximation. Cheers :-)

Comment: @FShrike it's from a set of excercises for Complex Analysis,given to a Greek University. I think that the professor had something else in his mind.....

Answer (score 1):

Using @FShrike's comment and cross multiplying we need to find the zeros of function
$$f(y)=(\pi -3 y) \cos (y)-k \sin(y) \qquad \qquad k=18\,\frac{ e^5-1}{e^5+1}$$ which, for $y \in (0,2\pi)$ shows three roots.

Working the small root, using series
$$f(y)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\pi  \cos \left(\frac{\pi  n}{2}\right)-(k+3 n) \sin
   \left(\frac{\pi  n}{2}\right)}{n!}\,y^n$$ Truncating to some order and using power series reversion
$$y=\frac{\pi }{k+3}-\frac{\pi ^3}{2 (k+3)^3}+\frac{\pi ^3 \left((k^2+12k+3) \left(9+\pi ^2\right)\right)}{6
   (k+3)^5}+\cdots$$

Using only the above terms, the *estimate* is
$y=\color{red}{0.1503}873$ while Newton method leads to
$y=0.1503578$ which is not bad.

Using twice more terms, this would give
$y=\color{red}{0.150357}603$
while Newton method leads to
$y=0.150357827$.

We could do the same around $y=\pi$ and $y=2\pi$ for the same accuracy.

When $y$ is known, just compute $x$.